# I'm having problems with my if else statement not taking the return from the if in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write this simple code for Javascript and it doesn't show me any errors in the code but when I run it the code works for the most part. It does not register the If statement but it will register the else. Everywhere I look they show me that I am basically right and I even tried different variables and Booleans but still have no luck

```
var userInput = prompt("Enter name");

if (userInput >= 4)
 {
  alert("You have a long name");
} 
else 
 {
  alert("You have a short name");
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to compare a string to a number

Comment: If you want the size of the string us `userInput.length` instead of `userInput`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `String.length` property to get the length of the string entered by the user.

```js
var userInput = prompt("Enter name");

if (userInput.length >= 4) {
  alert("You have a long name");
} else if(userInput.length < 4 && userInput.length > 0) {
  alert("You have a short name");
} else {
  alert("Name cannot be blank");
}
```

Read more here [String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).